# Cancelling std::cout code lines using preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, cout

One can remove all calls to `printf()` using `#define printf`. What if I have a lot of debug prints like `std::cout << x << endl;` ? How can I quickly switch off `cout <<` statements in a single file using preprocessor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NullStream can be a good solution if you are looking for something quick that removes debug statements. However I would recommend creating your own class for debugging, that can be expanded as needed when more debug functionality is required:

```
class MyDebug
{
    std::ostream & stream;
  public:
    MyDebug(std::ostream & s) : stream(s) {}
#ifdef NDEBUG
    template<typename T>
    MyDebug & operator<<(T& item)
    {
      stream << item;
      return *this;
    }
#else
    template<typename T>
    MyDebug & operator<<(T&)
    {
      return *this;
    }
#endif
};
```

This is a simple setup that can do what you want initially, plus it has the added benefit of letting you add functionality such as debug levels etc..

**Update:**
Now since manipulators are implemented as functions, if you want to accept manipulators as well (endl) you can add:

```
MyDebug & operator<<(std::ostream & (*pf)(std::ostream&))
{
  stream << pf;
  return *this;
}
```

And for all manipulator types (So that you don't have to overload for all manipulator types):

```
template<typename R, typename P>
MyDebug & operator<<(R & (*pf)(P &))
{
  stream << pf;
  return *this;
}
```

Be careful with this last one, because that will also accept regular functions pointers.

Comment: If I pass endl to this stream it gives error.. looks like T& item doesn't accept endl.. any clue how to overload it for that too ?

Comment: Hello, what kind of situation does operator<<(R & (*pf)(P &)) handle?
I found that everything works fine without it.

Answer (score 10):

As "unwind" already said, the quick solution is a do-nothing stream. There are better implementations though:

```
class NullStream {
    public:
    NullStream() { }
    template<typename T> NullStream& operator<<(T const&) { return *this; }
};
```

You still have a slight issue with `std::cout` since that's a sequence of three tokens, and you really don't want to redefine `std` or `cout` individually. A simple solution is

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    #define COUT std::cout
#else
    #define COUT NullStream()
#endif

COUT << "Hello, world" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

As a general principle logging to stdout should be avoided - far better to log to a logfile, and then you can use standard configuration tools to change log levels, or turn it off altogether.

Just my $0.02.....

Answer (score 5):

Substitute your debug output statements with something like this:

```
IFDBG(cout << result << endl);
```

Then you can define macros accordingly:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#  define IFDBG(x) x
#else
#  define IFDBG(x)
#endif
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it will work with `IFDBG(cout << foo(x,y) << std::endl);`. The comma is going to break the macro.

Comment: No, that won't break the macro, since macros can escape scope whithin parenthesis. However this call will break it: IFDBG(cout << foo<int, float>() << std::endl);

Answer (score 5):

Define this macro :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define MY_LOG std::cout
#else
    #define MY_LOG if(false) std::cout
#endif
```

This macro advantage is in compiler optimization

> If expressions placed inside those IFs are **constant and determinable at the time of compilation**, then you may be almost sure that the compiler has already removed them off the code for you...
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14657645/5052296

Comment: For me it's the best answer. Finally I solved this problem! Thank you @y30!

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do a preprocessor hack that defines a new stream-like class, with an instance named `cerr`, that just does nothing. If you're really lucky, the compiler will see that the function does nothing, and optimize the calls to `operator<<()` out.

Something like

```
class NullStream
{
public:
  NullStream();

  NullStream& operator<<(const std::string& text) { return *this; }
  // And operators for other types, too
}
static NullStream cerr;
```

This is quite the hack though, it's (far) better to go through your source and add proper support for logging.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a macro that replaces `cout` is not something you should upload to your VCS, but if you just do it temporarily during debugging, I think it serves its place. So you can just replace `cout` by `ostream(0)` like

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define cout ostream(0).flush()
#endif
```

This way, it works with both `std::cout` and plain `cout`, and `ostream` is available when including `<iostream>`. Writing into a `ostream(0)` is a no-op. The `flush` function call is done so that you get a non-const reference to it (so it also binds to non-member `operator<<` that's used for outputting `std::string` and others). As its type is `ostream`, it should behave exactly like `cout`.