# Is "std::cout" usable in Android-ndk

Tags: c++, console, android-ndk

In Android-ndk, we could use "__android_log_write", "__android_log_print", ... etc to output messages to the "LogCat" window. How about if I use "std::cout" to output some strings ? E.g.

```
std::cout << "some strings" << std::endl;
```

Where would the strings be sent.

It seems that Android does not have Console Applications and the above strings may not be sent. Could I redirect the "stdout" to a file so that sending strings to "std::cout" is equivalent to logging messages ?

Comment: subset: redirect stdout to logcat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531050/redirect-stdout-to-logcat-in-android-ndk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ printfs - Where's it appears in a Android native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426911/c-c-printfs-wheres-it-appears-in-a-android-native-code)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the Android documentation, **stdout & stderr** output to `/dev/null`. You can use the **[Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)** to achieve what you want.

> By default, the Android system sends stdout and stderr (System.out and System.err) output to /dev/null. In processes that run the Dalvik VM, you can have the system write a copy of the output to the log file. In this case, the system writes the messages to the log using the log tags stdout and stderr, both with priority I.
>     To route the output in this way, you stop a running emulator/device instance and then use the shell command setprop to enable the redirection of output. Here's how you do it:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

The system retains this setting until you terminate the emulator/device instance. To use the setting as a default on the emulator/device instance, you can add an entry to /data/local.prop on the device.

Comment: Tried this. It is not working. `/dev/null` is empty always

Answer (score 41):

You can create a class derived from `std::streambuf` which uses the Android specific functions to send the produced sequence of characters. I don't know where the default implementation of `std::cout` sends characters on Android, however. Basically, this would look something like this:

```
class androidbuf : public std::streambuf {
public:
    enum { bufsize = 128 }; // ... or some other suitable buffer size
    androidbuf() { this->setp(buffer, buffer + bufsize - 1); }

private:
    int overflow(int c)
    {
        if (c == traits_type::eof()) {
            *this->pptr() = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
            this->sbumpc();
        }
        return this->sync()? traits_type::eof(): traits_type::not_eof(c);
    }

    int sync()
    {
        int rc = 0;
        if (this->pbase() != this->pptr()) {
            char writebuf[bufsize+1];
            memcpy(writebuf, this->pbase(), this->pptr() - this->pbase());
            writebuf[this->pptr() - this->pbase()] = '\0';

            rc = __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "std", writebuf) > 0;
            this->setp(buffer, buffer + bufsize - 1);
        }
        return rc;
    }

    char buffer[bufsize];
};
```

To actually set up `std::cout` to write to this stream buffer, you would do something like this in your `main()` function:

```
int main() {
    std::cout.rdbuf(new androidbuf);
    ...
}
```

This create a memory leak for the one `androidbuf` stream which is, however, somewhat intentional: the stream may be written to after `main()` is exited and it is flushed when when `std::cout` gets destroyed. If you don't want this, you could either restore `std::cout`'s original stream buffer or set it to null and delete the return from `rdbuf()`:

```
   // avoid a one-time resource leak but don't get output afterwards:
   delete std::cout.rdbuf(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for another solution. But it involves more coding, I'll try it later.

Comment: Thank you, it's works. But it has several mistakes. Here is fixed version: https://gist.github.com/dzhioev/6127982

Comment: Thanks! I modified the code to actually work by copy&paste, hope it might help someone. (might be pending peer review)

Comment: Wow, you just made my life 100% easier! I wish I could give you more than an upvote

Comment: For me the code only displays the log when the buffer is full.

Comment: @pvallet: Yes, that is expected unless the stream is explicitly flushed, e.g., using `out << std::flush`. Sending character to external destinations is generally rather expensive and is normally minimized. You *can* disable the buffer in `androidbuf` causing `overflow()` to be called for each character (also introducing some extra overhead) and call `sync()` upon specific characters, e.g., `'\n'`. However, I'd stick with flushing the stream explicitly.

Comment: If someone is interested in flushing the buffer after every output, try this:
std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
#include <sstream>

class MyStream
{
private:
   std::stringstream m_ss;
   int m_logLevel;
public:

   MyStream(int Xi_logLevel)
   {
      m_logLevel = Xi_logLevel;
   };
   ~MyStream()
   {
      __android_log_print(m_logLevel,LOG_TAG,"%s", m_ss.str().c_str());
   }

   template<typename T> MyStream& operator<<(T const& Xi_val)
   {
      m_ss << Xi_val;
      return *this;
   }
};

#define MY_LOG(LOG_LEVEL) MyStream(ANDROID_LOG_##LOG_LEVEL) << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " : "
```

**PROS:**

(1) The messages are printed immediately.

**CONS:**

(1) You must to change your code (std::cout -> MY_LOG(X)).

(2) Each a single print produces an object and destroys it.

(***
[This answer base on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389600/5052296))

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to print log in android studio logcat.

Step 1: Add the following lines to your common header file.

```
#include <android/log.h>
    
#define LOGV(TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO   , TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN   , TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
```

Step 2: Now just call

```
LOGV("MYTAGNAME", "Hello!!");
LOGD("MYTAGNAME", "Hello!!");
LOGI("MYTAGNAME", "Hello!!");
LOGW("MYTAGNAME", "Hello!!");
LOGE("MYTAGNAME", "Hello!!");
```

Step 3: you can see logs in logcat as below.

[image]

Comment: Perfect simple answer. And it works. Just one thing, if you are using CMake you must also add  -llog into target_link_libraries:

target_link_libraries(<your_library_name> -llog)

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Dietmar Kühl is very good, but it do not work with boost.log from [Crystax NDK](https://www.crystax.net/). I found [another idea](https://codelab.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/how-to-use-standard-output-streams-for-logging-in-android-apps/) and have corrected it a little. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <android/log.h>

static int pfd[2];
static pthread_t thr;
static const char *tag = "myapp";

static void *thread_func(void*)
{
    ssize_t rdsz;
    char buf[128];
    while((rdsz = read(pfd[0], buf, sizeof buf - 1)) > 0) {
        if(buf[rdsz - 1] == '\n') --rdsz;
        buf[rdsz] = 0;  /* add null-terminator */
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, tag, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}

int start_logger(const char *app_name)
{
    tag = app_name;

    /* make stdout line-buffered and stderr unbuffered */
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    /* create the pipe and redirect stdout and stderr */
    pipe(pfd);
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    dup2(pfd[1], 2);

    /* spawn the logging thread */
    if(pthread_create(&thr, 0, thread_func, 0) == -1)
        return -1;
    pthread_detach(thr);
    return 0;
}
```

And its use:

```
...
start_logger("MyApp");
...
```

Now all output from boost.log to std::cout and std::cerr will be in logcat:

```
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>

...
boost::log::add_console_log(std::cout);
boost::log::add_common_attributes();

boost::log::sources::logger_mt lg;
BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello, World!";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870278/1756939 answer in here, but debugged and simplified as following.

- Managing EOF on overflow function is useless, it would stop logging afterwards.
- the return condition on overflow function is inverted so it didn't work
- the buffer copy on sync is useless, it can be done with only one buffer.
- the setp call on sync can be done with a simple pbump
- added the option to select different tag and log level for cout and cerr
- added a class StdStreamRedirector to simplify the assignment to cout and cerr and flush at shutdown.

```cpp
#ifndef STDSTREAMREDIRECTOR_H
#define STDSTREAMREDIRECTOR_H

#include <android/log.h>
#include <iostream>

class StreamBuf2Log : public std::streambuf {
public:
    enum Type { OUT, ERR };
    StreamBuf2Log(Type t) {
        this->setp(buffer, buffer + bufsize - 2); // extra space for \0 char at the end
        switch (t) {
            case OUT:
                PRIORITY = ANDROID_LOG_INFO;
                strcpy(TAG,"std::cout");
                break;
            case ERR:
                PRIORITY = ANDROID_LOG_ERROR;
                strcpy(TAG, "std::cerr");
                break;
        }
    }

private:
    int overflow(int c)
    {
        *this->pptr() = traits_type::to_char_type(c); // there is just enough space for c and \0 on buffer
        pbump(1);
        sync();
        return 0;
    }

    int sync()
    {
        int n = pptr () - pbase ();
        if (!n || (n == 1 && buffer[0] == '\n')) return 0; // spurious flushes removed
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        __android_log_write(PRIORITY, TAG, buffer);
        pbump (-n);  // Reset pptr().
        return 0;
    }

    static constexpr int bufsize = 2048;
    char TAG[10];
    android_LogPriority PRIORITY;
    char buffer[bufsize];
};

class StdStreamRedirector {
private:
    StreamBuf2Log outbuf;
    StreamBuf2Log errbuf;
public:
    StdStreamRedirector() : outbuf(StreamBuf2Log::OUT), errbuf(StreamBuf2Log::ERR) {
        std::cout.rdbuf(&outbuf);
        std::cerr.rdbuf(&errbuf);
    }
    ~StdStreamRedirector() {
        std::cout << std::flush;
        std::cerr << std::flush;
    }
};

#endif //STDSTREAMREDIRECTOR_H
```

To start the redirection at the loading of the so library and stopping when the so library use the following:

```cpp
#include "StdStreamRedirector.h"

StdStreamRedirector *redirector;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* /*reserved*/) {
    redirector = new StdStreamRedirector();
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void JNI_OnUnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* /*reserved*/) {
    delete redirector;
}
```