# Android NDK C++ library print log on android studio?

Tags: android, logging, android-ndk

Hi I am building an `C++` native library based on the android `NDK` tool. However, I couldn't figured out how to print log in the `C++` file to Android `logcat`. 
here is what I have done.

I have follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004255/cant-print-log-messages-from-jni-with-android-studio) guide. 
to add the 
    `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "log", "hi logg");`

include  `android/log.h`

and

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        moduleName "modulename"
        ldLibs "log"
    }
}
```

the app is able to compile but there's no `log` printed. Can someone help me?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but have you verified that the module is loaded and that the function that runs `__android_log_print()` is executed?