# Where does clog go in an Android NDK application?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-emulator, android-ndk

I'm porting my C++ application to Android using NDK and wonder where the clog out goes to?  I am trying to debug by adding print statements, but I cannot find where they are sent.  Where does clog get sent in a C++ application running under Android NDK?

Comment: Have you looked at the output of logcat?

Comment: No, where do I find `logcat`?

Comment: `adb logcat`, or if you've got a shell on the device/emulator, just type the command `logcat`. Also if you use Eclipse, it will show you the running log.

Comment: @mah I'm using Eclipse and the LogCat does not show my messages sent to `cout` or `clog`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see *[Is "std::cout" usable in Android-ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870174/is-stdcout-usable-in-android-ndk)*. TL;NR:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

Comment: Is this setting persistent if I rebuild and run my application again from eclipse?

Comment: It is persistent until device reboot. It does not relate to your app at all. It works on the device scope.