# Rust stdout not printing in Java application

Tags: java, rust, stdout, ffi

I'm using an android Java app for the GUI of my program, and am trying to debug the lower-level rust kernel for the GUI. Whereas stdout works on the java side, any printlns from rust side do not show up in the console (android studio). I'm using JNI-RS for the FFI on the rust side. Is this expected behavior? How might the problem be alleviated (without printing to files)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Android you have to use logcat instead of stdout (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870174/is-stdcout-usable-in-android-ndk)) . The one possible way is to use [android_logger](https://crates.io/crates/android_logger) or any other crate which provides logcat support.

You can found more information about stdout redirection [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531050/redirect-stdout-to-logcat-in-android-ndk).